# inline keyboard button make action change user url using php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, telegram, telegram-bot

i have a php code for telegram bot inline keyboard i want when i press one of the two buttons
i want to redirect the user to another page, look at my code is working but i dont know how to do this action on the inline keyboard

```
if ($telegram == "on"){
        $keyboard = json_encode([
            "inline_keyboard" => [
                [
                    [
                        "text" => "✅ ADMINPAGE ✅",
                        "callback_data" => "callbackone"
                    ],

                    [
                        "text" => "❌ HOMEPAGE ❌",
                        "callback_data" => "callbacktwo"
                    ],

                ]
            ]
        ]);
        $parameters = array(
            "chat_id" => $chat_id,
            "text" => $txt,
            'reply_markup' => $keyboard

        );
    
    
        $send = ($parameters);
        $website_telegram = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$bot_url}";
        $ch = curl_init($website_telegram . '/sendMessage');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($send));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) accepts an `url` parameter:

> `url`
>
> *Optional*. `HTTP` or `tg://` URL **to be opened when the button is pressed**.
> Links `tg://user?id=<user_id>` can be used to mention a user by their ID without using a username, if this is allowed by their privacy settings.

---

So you'll need something like:

```php
$keyboard = json_encode([
    "inline_keyboard" => [
        [
            [
                "text" => "✅ ADMINPAGE ✅",
                "url" => "https://example.com/admin"
            ],

            [
                "text" => "❌ HOMEPAGE ❌",
                "url" => "https://example.commin"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: how i can with the url send the response to server and control with this url the displayed page to user